# Find and replace problem

Tags: php, replace

My website, has 2 database tables. 1 of them have the `posts_table` and the other one have the videos.

At the moment i am getting the text images etc , normally from the `post_table` table.
In my CMS when we add a video there is added a short code

```
[media id=487 width=660 height=440]
```

This shortcode automaticly get the link of a video  from the `vid_table` where the id is the same as the shortcode.

So what i want is:

- I need to do the same thing that the short code do, when a video is added on CMS  the short code is showed in the post, i need to delete the shortcode and instead of it want to be played a video that has the link on the vid_table.

I have some problems with my english , so if you dont understand again please tell me.

Any kind of help will be great.

Thank you.

EDITED: So i  want to replace the whole media tag with a flash player, that plays the url that belongs to the ID in the media tag

BUMP !! CAN HELP PLEASE ?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what exactly is the question. You already posted an implementation for changing the media tag to a html element. Would you like to make a general parser for all tags matching the pattern `[object ...]` and render html elements based on the parameters of the tag? E.g `[link id=123]` would be replaced by `<a href="...">...</a>`

Comment: @Meo I think most people don't understand what you're after. for example, you mention a "table" without defining it. If it's an HTML table, you [shouldn't use regular expressions on the serialized HTML in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Please add more information about the table and hyperlink you speak of.

Comment: @phihag By table I believe s/he means "database table"

Comment: yes i mean database table sorry, and as i said in the post there is only the id given, i can get the id but how can i get the link that is associated with that id in a database table

Comment: @Meo how are you communicating with your database in other parts of your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a sophisticated problem actually. I was bored and made a basic tag parser. Right now it has some problems:

- HTML rendering should be implemented in a separated class (and a template engine such as Twig should do the rendering);
- Tag parsing is way too naive and will probably give you unexpected results if a tag's syntax is incorrect;
- `[media]` tag does not support IE. You would have to change the source itself (method `TagParser::renderMedia()`)

Some features to note:

- extra parameters will be rendered as attributes for `[link]` tag, e.g `[link id=25 class=foo]` will output `<a href="example.com" class="foo">example</a>`.
- parameters may contain spaces if you quote them: `[link id=25 class="foo bar"]` will output `<a href="example.com" class="foo bar">example</a>`
- If `DataProvider::findById()` does not return a `'content'` in its array, the parser will output `<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>`

The code is too long to paste here, you can find it on [gist](https://gist.github.com/1191703). Just put each file in the directory specified by the first commented line and you should be set. Run `example.php` to see it in action. You can find out some more details about using this script by looking at the unit test.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want exactly?, you can get media id out of the text using

```
$text = 'some stuff [media id=468 width=660 height=440] more stuff';

preg_match("/media id=(.*) w/",$text, $results);
$result = $results[0];
$result = str_replace("media id=","",$result);

$result = str_replace("w","",$result);

$id = $result;
```

Comment: He wants to replace the whole media tag with a flash player, that plays the url that belongs to the ID in the media tag.